# Ext Js 4 - CellModel Multi Select not working?

Tags: extjs, cell, extjs4, multi-select

I am trying to implement the `Ext.selection.CellModel` with `mode: 'MULTI'` however the grid still only allows one cell to be selected at a time?
Below is some sample code:

```
var cellmodel = new Ext.selection.CellModel({
    mode: 'MULTI'
});

 var grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
    store: store,
    selModel: cellmodel,
    multiSelect: true,
    ....
 });
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug within the Ext code itself?

Comment: There is no `CellModel` bundled with ExtJS 4, can you show me where you got this code from?

Comment: @Jaitsu: its here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.selection.CellModel

Comment: it should be selType:'rowmodel',multiSelect: true,

Answer (score 0):

Multiple selection is currently unsupported with CellModel selection type. A silly omission, but true as of and up to 4.1.3. Looks like 4.2 (due soon) will have the same limitation.

Someone has developed a ux, but I haven't tested it yet.

https://gist.github.com/brian428/3695036